# Magento 2: How to check Selling Fast Products?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, stock, inventory

Would like to check Selling Fast Products List. 
It will be managed Product Wise.

```
Example:
For Product A, Qty: 50, Limit Qty: 5
For Product B, Qty: 100, Limit Qty: 2
```

If Product A reached Qty 5 then it will be Selling Fast.

For Product B if it reaches Qty 2 then it will be Selling Fast.

Comment: Where would you like to see this output? Is this a one off script or in the admin?

Comment: Need to do Admin Configuration for Limit Qty Product wise. On basis of Order Completed reaches to Limit Qty. "Selling Fast" Label on Frontend for that product Enable Automatically